# Magento Group by 'name' in product collection

Tags: magento, collections, filtering

For some reason i have added multiple products with the same name in the admin. But on the product listing page i do not want to show duplicate products by name

i have created "catalog_product_collection_load_before" observer and i have started with the following code

```
public function catalogCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

}
```

i am able to get product collection but i am not able to find a way so that i can remove duplicate products.

Comment: If you don't want to make product visible in frontend, you can disable that product through admin side.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide a product from product list, you don't need to do observer stuff. Magento has already provisions to do it.

You just want to put that product's `visibility` to `not visible individually` or make that product `status` to `disable`. That will do the trick.

These are the step that you need to follow

1. go to `catalog  >  Manage Products`
2. Select the product that you need to disable from frontend
3. Make it `visibility` to `not visible individually`
4. save

Done !

Comment: i know i can use product visibility to filter product collection, but i have modified advance search to search attribute for all products regardless of visibility and on the advance search results page that approach will not work.